# Unable to Display Phylogenetic Tree using phylotree in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, phylogeny

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm having trouble displaying a phylogenetic tree using the **`phylotree`** library in a React project. I've tried to follow the library's documentation and examples, but I'm not getting the expected output. Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// @ts-ignore
import { phylotree, TreeRender } from 'phylotree';

export default function Home() {

    const tree = () => {
        const tree_nwk = new phylotree('(A,(B));');

        const renderedTree = tree_nwk.render({
            height: 1000,
            width: 1000,
            'left-right-spacing': 'fit-to-size',
            'top-bottom-spacing': 'fit-to-size',
            container: 'a'
        });

        renderedTree.show();
        console.log('aqui');
        console.log(tree_nwk);
    };

    tree();

    return (
        <div className='a'>
          Hello World
        </div>
    );
}
```

The issue is that the phylogenetic tree is not being displayed on the page as expected. I'm using the **`phylotree`** library and calling the **`renderedTree.show()`** method, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended.

I've ensured that the **`phylotree`** library is correctly installed and imported. The console logs within the **`tree`** function are being triggered, so I know that part of the code is executing.

Could someone please help me identify what I might be doing wrong here? Is there something I'm missing or misunderstanding about how to use the **`phylotree`** library to render a phylogenetic tree in a React component?

Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I've tried using the **`phylotree`** library to render a phylogenetic tree within a React component. I followed the library's documentation and examples to create the tree and render it on the page. Specifically, I've used the **`tree_nwk.render()`** method to generate the rendered tree and called **`renderedTree.show()`** to display it.

I was expecting that the phylogenetic tree would be displayed within the **`<div>`** element with the class name **`'a'`**. The tree should have a height and width of 1000, and the spacing should be adjusted to fit the size of the container. The console logs **`'aqui'`** and the tree object are being printed, indicating that the code within the **`tree`** function is executing.

However, despite following these steps, the phylogenetic tree is not showing up on the page as I anticipated. Instead, only the "Hello World" text is visible within the **`<div>`** element.

I suspect that there might be an issue with how I'm using the **`phylotree`** library or configuring the rendering options. But I'm unsure about what exactly might be causing the problem.

If anyone has experience with using the **`phylotree`** library in a React project or has encountered a similar issue, I would greatly appreciate your insights and guidance. Thank you for your help!